# margin location in tufte-class

Tags: margins, double-sided, tufte

By default I have observed that the margin is always on same side of the page, i.e irrespective of the page being the left page or right page the margin is always on the right hand side of the page. Is there a way to make the margin on left page appear on the left and margin on the right page appear on the right?

Comment: It's by design; see the `sample-book.pdf` example that forms the class documentation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `symmetric` option of the class.

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
test\sidenote{this}
\lipsum
test\sidenote{that} 
\end{document}
```